# th border-top have space when print

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to print the content of a div
the header element `th` has top and bottom border which is fine in any browser, but when printed the border has small space between the th

So I tried to move the border style to element `tr` which is also fine in any browser, but when printed no border appears

Any solutions?

The CSS:

```
.derDruck tr:first-child
{
    font-size:16px;
    border-top:1px;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-bottom:1px;
    border-color:#000;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<table class="derDruck">
    <tr><th>NO.</th><th>DESCRIPTION</th><th class="alCenter">TIME</th><th class="alRight">PRICE</th><th class="alRight">DISC</th><th class="alRight">AMOUNT</th></tr>
```